# Javascript: how to assign "selected" to an "option" element

Tags: javascript

I am trying to assign an option element the "selected" attribute, in javascript, but I am not getting it. Could someone show me an example please?

Comment: Could you first include the code where you attempt to do this?

Comment: you can check [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) for the syntax, 

if you wanted a default value to be selected use         <option value="user-value1" selected>user value1</option>

Comment: if you wanted a default value to be selected use "selected"

<select id="cars">
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>

if you are iterating using javascript, if the matching condition is identfied, then set use selectedIndex to set the select option, like car.selectedIndex = index

Comment: I don't need to put a code, I just need an example of how via javascript I put an option with the 'selected' attribute!

Answer (score 1):

you can just add an attribute using [`.addAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) function:

```
const myElement = document.getElementById("myElement");
myElement.addAttribute('selected', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

I remembered how to do it

```
productCategoryInput[2].selected = true;
```

A tip for you to make this community better. If you don't know the answer, get out of the question, don't be demeaning it.